# Restricting a process to write-only access to a single directory

Tags: .net, windows, security

We have a server process which handles user requests. Per user request we need to create a temp directory to which the process must write sensible data. As the process can somewhat be controlled by user parameters we want to make "extra sure" that it can never write outside its temporary directory + it can never read from other temporary directories of parallel requests.

We thought about creating a user per request, impersonate it and thereby restricting access, however, having one user per parallel request seems very "impactful".

We heard about restricted access tokens, but don't know how to use them properly. But maybe there are even other, better options to secure our process.

**Question:** What's a good and lightweight way to restrict a user request to being able to write only to a specific directory?

We're running on .NET 4.7.1 on Windows Server 2016.

Comment: May the downvoter please elaborate so that I can improve the question? Thanks!